# How to add the answers for a -for loop- to a list?

Tags: python

'''Trying to add the answers for this for loop to a list. '''

```
import random
name = []

print ("Welcome to the multiplication Game")
cont = 0
name = input(str"Please enter your name")
base = input (str("Enter the number you want to practice on"))
por = [x for x in range(1,10)]
random.shuffle(por) #the numbers in the list will be sorted in a random order
for i in por:
   x= int(input("{} x {} = ".format(base, i)))
   if (x) == int(base*i):
        print ("Correcto!")
        bandera= False
        correcto+=1
    if (x) != int(base*i): 
        print ("Incorrecto!")
        print("La respuesta correcta es ", int(base*i))
        errores +=1
```

''' i have now decided to take another path with this and did not add the user inputs to a list '''

Comment: can you provide an example with input/output of the program you want to write?

Comment: 10 x 2 = (user input) 10x7= (user input) ... and so on,... i need to get all of the answers into a list so I can check if the answer is correct or not :(

Comment: show your code in question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted ?

```
import random
number = input("Enter your number : ")

numbersAlreadyUsed = []

while len(numbersAlreadyUsed) < 11:
    # get a random number within this range
    randNumber = random.randrange(1,11)
    if(randNumber not in numbersAlreadyUsed):
        print("{0} x {1} = {2}" .format(number,randNumber, randNumber * int(number)))
        numbersAlreadyUsed.append(randNumber)
else:
    print("we are done!")
```

Please note that the code can be refactored a ton and is not beautiful!

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, in this case, the user should be able to answer to each one of the multiplications and they should be able to see if their answer is correct or not :(